# Paypal Express Checkout.js - populate product details

Tags: javascript, paypal, checkout

I'm trying to populate the product details under transaction details with Paypal Express Checkout.js. I was able to pass the total amount correctly, but I need to get each product name and quantity.

[image: Product Details]

```
import React from 'react';
import PaypalExpressBtn from 'react-paypal-express-checkout';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const onSuccess = (payment) => {
            // 1, 2, and ... Poof! You made it, everything's fine and dandy!
                    console.log("Payment successful!", payment);
                    // You can bind the "payment" object's value to your state or props or whatever here, please see below for sample returned data
                    this.props.reset()
                    alert("Pagamento efetuado com sucesso!")

        }

        const onCancel = (data) => {
            // The user pressed "cancel" or closed the PayPal popup
            console.log('Payment cancelled!', data);
            // You can bind the "data" object's value to your state or props or whatever here, please see below for sample returned data
        }

        const onError = (err) => {
            // The main Paypal script could not be loaded or something blocked the script from loading
            console.log("Error!", err);
            // Because the Paypal's main script is loaded asynchronously from "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"
            // => sometimes it may take about 0.5 second for everything to get set, or for the button to appear
        }

        let env = 'sandbox'; // you can set this string to 'production'
        let currency = 'BRL'; // you can set this string from your props or state  
        // let total = 1;  // this is the total amount (based on currency) to charge
        // Document on Paypal's currency code: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

        const client = {
            sandbox:    'Aat8DGkJm-8JrK-8SsvIvClaJpy2EohIlw8x5wDkK1DfuAKpJFHeTH0dNRg3xFywRkhn-375Fjlproca',
            production: 'YOUR-PRODUCTION-APP-ID',
        }
        // In order to get production's app-ID, you will have to send your app to Paypal for approval first
        // For your sandbox Client-ID (after logging into your developer account, please locate the "REST API apps" section, click "Create App" unless you have already done so):
        //   => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/
        // Note: IGNORE the Sandbox test AppID - this is ONLY for Adaptive APIs, NOT REST APIs)
        // For production app-ID:
        //   => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

        // NB. You can also have many Paypal express checkout buttons on page, just pass in the correct amount and they will work!
        return (
            <PaypalExpressBtn env={env} client={client} currency={currency} total={this.props.total} onError={onError} paymentOptions={this.props.cartList} onSuccess={onSuccess} onCancel={onCancel} />
        );
    }
}
```

How would I be able to pass each product name and unit to "Product Details"? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [react-paypal-button-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button-v2) instead of [react-paypal-express-checkout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-express-checkout)

Comment: Is react-paypal-express-checkout deprecated?

Comment: It uses paypal payments api v1. Refer `paymentOptions` in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-express-checkout#props

Comment: @DaviMello You should use PayPal Smart Payment Buttons instead of PayPal Express Checkout Buttons